# CustomReportItem Report Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, custom-controls

I am trying to design a custom report item for SSRS. Is there a way to access report parameters within the EvaluateReportItemInstance function when implementing the ICustomReportItem?

Please note that I am **not** trying to access custom properties for the custom report item being designed. I wish to access all of the parameters declared in a report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

This needs to be done when implementing the CustomReportItemDesigner, not the ICustomReportItem. For example:

```
public class MyCustomReportItemDesigner : Microsoft.ReportDesigner.CustomReportItemDesigner
{
    public override void InitializeNewComponent()
    {
        //this.Report.ReportParameters;
```